# Concatenate Integers without calculate PHP

Tags: php, date

On my database, dates are in the format `DD-MM-YYYY`. But for a `SELECT`, I need to be between two dates.
I know I must use `BETWEEN` syntax but with this, I need the date to be in the format `YYYY/MM/DD`.
So here's my code to change the syntax :

```
// my URL is : '.../pdf.php?date1=22-05-2015&date2=29-05-2015'
$date1=explode('-',$_GET["date1"]); // $_GET["date1"] = '22-05-2015'
$date2=explode('-',$_GET["date2"]); // $_GET["date2"] = '29-05-2015'

$date1_good = $date1[2].'/'.$date1[1].'/'.$date1[0];
$date2_good = $date2[2].'/'.$date2[1].'/'.$date2[0];
```

The problem is, `$date1_good` and `$date2_good` are now float values and not a string like `'2015/05/29'`.
I have tried using `strval()` and `(string)` but nothing worked.
Do you have any idea to make it work ? Thank you !

Comment: Why you were doing it in this way if you can simply achieve it using `date` or `datetime` function

Comment: I doubt that the two bottom lines using the `.` concatenation operator return a float value. They certainly do return a string. There must be something else wrong, maybe the way you dump those values. start by checking what values `$date1` and `$date2` really contain.

Comment: this code works good. the problem is in input of GET, i think - https://eval.in/372351

Comment: my GET inputs are `22-05-2015` && `29-05-2015`, I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @tektiv look my eval link

Comment: @anantkumarsingh When i do strtotime(...), with the first GET I have `1432245600` and when I date('Y/m/d', ...) this I get `18.31818181818`.

Comment: please put `var_dump($date1); $date1_good = $date1[2].'/'.$date1[1].'/'.$date1[0];  var_dump($date1_good);` and show the result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple to do like this:-

```
$date1_good = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_GET["date1"]));
$date2_good = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_GET["date2"]));
```

Note:- I gave an example just change format according to your wish. Good-luck. Thanks. check this:-

```
<?php

$_GET["date1"] = '22-05-2015';
$_GET["date2"]= '29-05-2015';
$date1_good = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_GET["date1"]));
$date2_good = date('Y/m/d',strtotime($_GET["date2"]));

echo $date1_good.'----------------'.$date2_good;

?>
```

Output:-  http://prntscr.com/7aofp6

Comment: I thought it could work .. but it still returns the same float value as before

Comment: tektiv - it shouldn't return float values, using the date() function will return it as a date object or not at all.

Comment: I edited my post to show you GET values and the URL .. maybe that will be the problem

Comment: Ok I just get it ... when I put `$date1_good` in the console, it calculates it then it outputs it ... Sorry I bothered you for this

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("23/10/2009"));
```

Comment: chek your quote. it's funkey quote not single quote. Also you do opposite what OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do it using `DateTime` function as

```
$date1 = "22-05-2015";
$date2 = "29-05-2015";
$date_1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y",$date1);
$date_2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y",$date2);
echo $date_1->format('Y/m/d')."<br>";
echo $date_2->format('Y/m/d');
```